# Using Java reflections to get class variables

Tags: java, android

I have the following class:

```
public final class ClassMap {

    public static final Class HELLO = HelloActivity.class;

}
```

I want to be able to access `HelloActivity.class` knowing the string `"HELLO"`. I've tried the following:

```
Field classField = ClassMap.class.getField("HELLO");
```

But that returns a `Field` object. How can I get a `Class` object back?

Thanks!

Comment: Your ultimate goal is a bit fuzzy.  Are you trying to get an instance of an object described by `"HELLO"`, or are you trying to execute a method contained in the `HelloActivity` class?

Comment: You might find it easier to create a normal `Map<String, Class>` in your class and use that instead of using reflection to find fields.  EG `Map<String, Class> activities = new HashMap<String, Class>(); activities.put("HELLO", HelloActivity.class);`.

Comment: Yep, my coworker suggested this too and that's what I'm going to do.

Answer (score 3):

Now that you have the `Field` object representing the field, ask for the value, i.e. call [`classField.get(Object obj)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#get-java.lang.Object-).

Since your field is `static`, the `obj` parameter will be ignored, and you should just give a `null` value. Javadoc says so:

> If the underlying field is a static field, the `obj` argument is ignored; it may be null.

So, do this:

```
Field classField = ClassMap.class.getField("HELLO");
Object value = classField.get(null);
```

Comment: Thanks! Although I may not use reflections, this is the right answer to my question. Will accept as soon as it lets me